# Solving (apparently convex under constraints) nonlinear system of equations - Modified linear regression

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, linear-regression

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time and I am excited to share it with this brilliant community!

**Question**

I am basically doing a modified version of linear regression. I have multiple sources of features, and want to weight each source such that the sum of the source weights $= 1.$ In other words, for each source's feature matrix $X_{iSource}^{(\text{nExamples},\,\text{nFeatures})}$, parameter matrix $B^{(\text{nFeatures})}$, source weighting vector $S^{(\text{nSources})}$ and target matrix $Y^{(\text{nExamples})}$, 
$$\min_{B,S}  \sum_{\text{nExamples}}[(\sum_{iSource = 1}^{nSources}s_{iSource}X_{iSource}B) - Y]^2$$
$$\sum_{iSource = 1}^{nSources}s_{iSource} = 1$$
(sorry if my syntax is off... its been a while since school)

**Motivation**

Well, for a while I have been doing a search on $S$, and solving for $B$ given some value of $S$. This is fine when $S$ is small, not so much when $S$ is large. I have been doing this for a few years now, and I have been plotting MSE vs $S$ when $\text{nSources} \le 3.$ Every plot I see is convex! So for a while, I've got it stuck in my head that there should be a closed form solution for $B$ and $S.$ I have spent too many hours and have determined I don't have the background (or know where to find the background) to solve this problem. Any and all suggestions are much appreciated!

edit: I realized that I was misrepresenting the problem. After fixing it up, the cost function is quite a mess. Perhaps a cleaner representation might lead to an easier solution - any suggestions would be appreciated... Apologies for those who have already answered!

Comment: It's bit more straight-forward to solve for $BS$ together - you can use the method in cardinal's solution here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9801/analytical-solution-to-linear-regression-coefficient-estimates. In practice, this equation is hardly ever used - it's usually more efficient to use stochastic gradient descent and iterate to the answer. Now, of course, the question comes up what do you do once you have $BS?$ How would you find $B$ from $BS,$ when, I'm assuming, the matrices aren't square? Have to think about that...

Comment: Couldn't you just set $S_i=1/\text{nSources},$ and weight them equally?

Comment: I definitely could set $S$ as you suggest. However, I would expect to have an lower MSE if I leave $S$ as a parameter to be solved.  (also, thanks for the formatting help!)

Comment: I don't think I agree that you can do better with an unspecified $S.$ Consider $\beta=BS.$ Then minimizing $\sum(X\beta-Y)^2$ is the standard linear regression problem, with solution $\beta=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y.$ This minimizes the MSE $\sum(X\beta-Y)^2,$ and there's no $\beta$ that performs better than $(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y.$ If you mess around with $B$ and $S,$ the multiplication of $BS$ still must be done, yielding the same $\beta$ that minimizes the MSE.

Comment: Ahhh, you are correct. And I realize I have written problem incorrectly! Sorry, give me a minute and I will clean it up...

Comment: I'd just write $SXB$ instead of the complicated sum you have there.

Comment: I'm not sure your sizes match up, anymore. If $S$ is $\text{nSources}\times 1,$ then  there's no way it can multiply $X$ if the dimension of $X$ are $\text{nExamples}\times\text{nFeatures}.$ What are the sizes of everything?

Comment: I should have clarified, I updated the dimensions in post as well. perhaps a plain written example would help; I have weather data for 3 weather stations. Each station provides temperature and wind data for every hour. I want to use those features to predict ice-cream sales. However, I want to optimally combine the 3 weather stations into 1 "aggregate station", then determine the relationship between the "aggregate station" and ice-cream sales. (thank you for your patience)

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea what $X_{iSource}^{(\text{nExamples},\,\text{nFeatures})}$ means. In the sum, you seem to indicate that $X$ has nSource entries, and it's a vector. Is that correct?

Comment: No, its not :P. I am trying to avoid using tensors greater than 2 dimensions. I think it should be $X(nSources, nExamples, nFeatures)$. I mean to say that for each source, there is a matrix where the columns represent features, and the rows represent examples.